# Warning message after clicking on react icon button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-icons

i have used FaEye, FaEyeSlash react icons as you can see in the below login code but every time i click on them i get the following warning message,i want that not to happen.note that i was using tailwindcss, but to fix this problem i tried using normal css.

Login.jsx

```
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { Link, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { FaEye, FaEyeSlash } from "react-icons/fa";
import { UserContext } from "../App";

function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [inputType, setInputType] = useState("password");
  const [icon, setIcon] = useState(<FaEye />);
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState("");

const {state, dispatch} = useContext(UserContext);

  function handleToggle(e) {
    if (inputType === "password") {
      setInputType("text");
      setIcon(FaEyeSlash);
    } else {
      setInputType("password");
      setIcon(FaEye);
    }
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = { email, password };
    console.log(`email: ${email}, password: ${password}`);
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/user/login", user)
      .then((res) =>{
        console.log(res.data.user)
        dispatch({ type: "USER",payload: {name: res.data.user, logStatus: true, identity: res.data.identity}});
        if ((res.data.identity.id === "Admin") && (res.data.identity.approved === false)){
          setSuccess(
            `${res.data.user},please wait for the Admins to approve your account!`
            );
        }else{
            setSuccess(
              `welcome ${res.data.user} you are successfully Logged in!`
            );
        }
      }
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        //console.log(`ERROR is ${err}`);
        setSuccess("Incorrect password or email");
      });
  }

  if(state.logStatus){
   return <Navigate to="/profile" state={{mes: success }} />
  }

  return (
    
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="text-center text-lg text-red-500 font-semibold">{success}</div>
      <div className="h-auto w-5/12 border mx-auto rounded-2xl mt-3 ">
        <div className="h-2 bg-indigo-400 rounded-t-2xl mb-5 "></div>
        <div className="font-bold text-2xl text-center">Sign In</div>
        <div className="px-16">
          <div className="mt-5 ">
            <label htmlFor="email" className="block font-semibold  ">
              Email address
            </label>
            <input
              type="email"
              className="border h-5 w-full px-3 py-5 rounded-md focus:outline-2 focus:outline-blue-600"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="Enter email"
              id="email"
              required
            />
          </div>

          <div style={{position: 'relative'}}>
            <label
              htmlFor="pass"
              className="block font-semibold mt-5"
            >
              Password
            </label>
            <input
              type={inputType}
              className="border h-5 w-full px-3 py-5 rounded-md focus:outline-2 focus:outline-blue-600"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="Enter password"
              id="pass"
              required
            />
            <span style={{position: 'absolute', top:36, right:15}} onClick={handleToggle}>
              {icon}
            </span>
          </div>

          <div className="">
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="mt-5 text-white bg-blue-600 border h-10 w-full py-2 rounded-md"
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-around">
            <p className="mb-5 mt-3 text-left">
              New here?
              <Link to="/sign-up" className="text-blue-600">
                Register
              </Link>
            </p>
            <p className="mb-5 mt-3 text-right ">
              Forgot
              <Link to="/password-reset" className="text-blue-600">
                password?
              </Link>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
  


export default Login;
```

The warning:

```
bundle.js:17688 Warning: Invalid values for props $$typeof, type on tag. Either remove them &nbsp; from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep them in the DOM. For details, see https://reactjs.org/link/attribute-behavior
   at svg at IconBase at span at div at div at div at form at Login .svg at IconBase at span at div at div at div at form at Login (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:3883:76 undefined)
   at RenderedRoute .RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:278126:5 undefined)
   at Routes .Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:278563:5 undefined)
   at Routing at App .Routing at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:349:78 undefined)
   at Router .Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:278501:15 undefined)
   at BrowserRouter .BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:276818:5 undefined)
```

Comment: I would avoid putting components in state. Have the state as a string or boolean, and then conditionally check what that state is in the JSX, and switch between the two icons.

Comment: you can try to `setIcon("FaEyeSlash")` and render the `Component` conditionally based on `icon` state

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh that just gives another error, does not work.

Comment: @Andy,well that is possible thanks ,i have mentioned it on the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my mistake was i forgot to put the components between the tags < and /> like this

```
setIcon(<FaEyeSlash />);
```

In the handleToggle function,that is why it was showing me that warning and that is what has worked for me.but also i can do the samething and save even the icon state from even needing it by just rendering the icon based on only inputType state.like this

```
<span
              className="absolute top-9 right-3.5 "
              onClick={handleToggle}
            >
              { inputType === "password"? <FaEye /> : <FaEyeSlash /> }
            </span>
```